# How to speed up a query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table that every request to the server, stores on it.
For each request I will check that it is banned or not.
For example it is a query:

```
select * from requests where request_sessID = '4bc0331d983000902b4718c80f12e9b3' AND request_time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 3600) AND request_isEnable = 1
```

I also set the engine from InnoDB to MyISAM and row_format to Dynamic but nothing changed.
My Hardware is very strong but it took about a minute to execute !
I am a programmer and newbie to mysql
How can Speed Up this query?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you execute the query for me andpost the result? `desc requests;`

Comment: Have you created any indexes?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to get all fields? Using `SELECT *` is not good practice.

Comment: @JohnWoo excuse me, but I am new to mysql. Can you explain more about your request? Tnx

Comment: @eggyal Yes, request_id is primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many entries do you have in your table? Billions?

I don't think so that you can speed up your request, but you need to create a [covered index](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/tag/covering-index/) in your table.

It could be like the following, but you need to take a look of the theory first to write the field in the right order (field with most possibilities first, ...)(link above)

```
ALTER TABLE requests
  ADD INDEX (request_sessID, request_time, request_isEnable);
```

Comment: I have 51 millions rows on it. Its Size is about 4 GB

Comment: In that case, you MUST have an index to be efficient

Comment: request_id is now primary key

Comment: To be really efficient, index the query condition like explain in my answer instead of the request_id field

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. It is still slow but... Much better now